# Create one div for each row of array fetched from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

We have a bunch of data in a MySQL database which call by using this phpcode:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `dmt_objects` WHERE PipelineAndWorkflow = 'RWP WF  Ready for 4Sprint' ORDER BY `Team` DESC  ;";
                        $select_projects = mysql_query($query);
$project_array = mysql_fetch_array($select_projects);
                        $json_project_array = json_encode($project_array);
```

However, we would no like to create one div for each team. If its ten teams we want to creat ten divs. We tried something like this in our HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var project_array = $json_project_array;

number_of_teams = project_array.length;

for(var i = 0; i < number_of_teams; i++){ 

var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.className = 'project_array['Team']';
                }
</script>
```

However, it don't seam to work, even if put
    document.write(i);
in the for loop instead of trying to creat a div.

Comment: you can use php to add div

Comment: okay, right, how do I do that?

Comment: You can't do var project_array = $json_project_array;. You're trying to do straight PHP inside javascript tags, without declaring it as PHP. You would atleast need to echo out the $json_project_array where you are using it (<?php echo $json_project_array; ?>), but what @raveenanigam has suggested is a better way to do it (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the code that will give you the output you desire...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `dmt_objects` WHERE PipelineAndWorkflow = 'RWP WF  Ready for 4Sprint' ORDER BY `Team` DESC  ;";
$select_projects = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($select_projects) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_projects)) {
        echo '<div>'.$row['Team'].'</div>';
    }
}
```

Also, do yourself a favor and change your code to `pdo_mysql`. `mysql` has been deprecated and will soon be removed. When this happens your code will stop functioning completely.

**Reference**

[pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `dmt_objects` WHERE PipelineAndWorkflow = 'RWP WF  Ready for 4Sprint' ORDER BY `Team` DESC  ;";
$select_projects = mysql_query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($select_projects) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_projects)) {

    echo '<div class="'.$row[yourcolumnname].'"></div>';
}

}
```

Comment: Great! However his code created multipel divs for each team. In the database, one team can be connected to multiple objects and for each object it is connected to, we now create a div...

Comment: Fixed it by addning '$team = array();' and 'if($row['Team'] !== "" && (in_array($row['Team'], $team) == False)){  
  echo '<div class="Teams" id="'.$row['Team'].'"></div>';
  array_push($team, $row['Team']);
}'